# Access Loop & Run Query for Every Record in a Table

Tags: loops, ms-access, recordset

I couldn't find an answer anywhere that fits the bill for what I'm trying to do. Here is my Scenario.

I have the following:

1. Table titled "Vendors" that contains a list of Vendor Numbers.
2. Several queries written to pull and calculate the performance data
   from our MRP (SAP)
3. Table titled "Vendor_Performance" that will contain a bunch of KPI
   data calculated in a couple of queries.

I need a method to loop through the list of supplier numbers in the "Vendors" table one by one and write the data to the appropriate fields created in "Vendor Performance"

I'm sure I need a RecordSets, but I don't have much experience with RecordSets and I can't find how to do it with a query.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why is this necessary? Why can't you just do table joins in query?

Comment: Hi June7. Thanks for your comment. I'm not familiar with table joins. How would that work?

Comment: Building queries that join related tables is basic functionality of relational database. Since I don't know your data structure, can't advise how to accomplish what you want. Yes, VBA and recordsets may be one option. So could be query using DLookup domain aggregate function. When you have some code with specific issue, post it for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was incredibly simple...I just needed to join the Table with the vendor info and the master query. Duh.

The I tied the Vendor Table to the two queries as June7 suggested, in the end it required one more query to be written but it did the job.